# PowerShell logic to remove objects from Array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to remove objects from an array that contain duplicates and only keep the ones with the highest number in `TasteCode`. The example below is highly simplified, but it shows the problem.

**Example:**

```
$Fruits
Name   | Color  | TasteCode
-----    ------   ---------
Apple  | Red    | 2
Apple  | Red    | 3
Peer   | Green  | 0
Banana | Yellow | 1
Banana | Yellow | 0
Banana | Yellow | 3
```

**Desired solution:**

```
Name   | Color  | TasteCode
-----    ------   ---------
Apple  | Red    | 3
Peer   | Green  | 0
Banana | Yellow | 3
```

I've already succeeded in gathering the ones that need to be removed, but it doesn't work out quite well:

```psh
$DuplicateMembers = $Fruits | Group-Object Name | Where Count -GE 2
$DuplicateMembers | ForEach-Object {

    $Remove = $_.Group | Sort-Object TasteCode | Select -First ($_.Group.Count -1)

    $Fruits = Foreach ($F in $Fruits) {
        Foreach ($R in $Remove) {
            if (($F.Name -ne $R.Name) -and ($F.TasteCode -ne $R.TasteCode)) {
                $F
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't work out quite well? You always take the highest `tastecode` in this data?

Comment: Yes, I always take the object with the highest `TasteCode` for that specific `Fruit.Name`. The problem is that in the end there are duplicate rows in the Array because of the `Foreach` on the remove part I think.

Comment: Only one Color for one Name or multiple allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about not performing a remove, but just sort on `tastecode` descending and taking just one first result?

```psh
$DuplicateMembers = $Fruits | Group-Object Name 
$DuplicateMembers | ForEach-Object {
    $Outcome = $_.Group | Sort-Object TasteCode -descending | Select -First 1
    $Outcome
}
```

This way you should not bother to remove anything form the result of this query.

Comment: Thank you Vesper, great tip! Same as jisaak so a +1 for the good thinking, as I totally didn't see that.

Comment: There's a subtle difference in our approaches - I followed your code that first groups then sorts, he first sorts then groups, the difference is in performance, and only prominent if there's a real lot of data in that `$fruits` equivalent of yours.

Comment: You're right Vesper, but it's not containing so much data so performance is not the issue now. But I'll keep it in mind for the future, where it can come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the fruits by TasteCode, group it by name and select the first 1 of each group:

```powershell
$result = $Fruits | sort TasteCode -Descending | group Name | % { $_.Group | select -first 1}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right this is a lot simpler than I initially though. Thank you very much for this great tip!

Comment: @DarkLite1 I had just assumed you were looking at something more complicated and was going to recommend an older question of your where you created a true clone of an object. Glad you found your answer.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if this is slower than multiple sorts on a large database. Say there are 10k groups with 10k items in each, totalling 100m, I think sorting 100m objects first is a lot slower than grouping first, then sorting each group. If you need the output sorting by taste code, just sort it once collected.

Comment: No problem Matt, been in the code a bit too long today I think. Didn't see the trees through the wood anymore. And you're right, I did a question about fruits already, but it's easy to demonstrate like this. You know I like pears right? ;)

Comment: @DarkLite1 I remembered because of "peers"

Comment: @Matt I know that one gave it away ;)